# F# records and list sorting

Tags: list, sorting, f#, records

I am fairly new to F# and am messing around with records and ways to store/sort them. What i have now is a this, which works fairly nicely... i think. Now seeing how this is a Functional first language i wanted to try and do a selection sort of this list of records i have made. Is there way to access the elements in the records so that i can sort by age? or am i thinking about this in the wrong way

```
module RecordTypes = 
    type Student = 
        {
            Name : string
            mutable age : int
            mutable major : string
        }

    let studentOne = { Name = "bob" ; age = 20 ; major = "spanish" }
    let studentTwo= { Name = "sally" ; age = 18 ; major = "english" }
    let studentThree = { Name = "frank" ; age = 22 ; major = "history" }
    let studentFour = { Name = "lisa" ; age = 19 ; major = "math" }
    let studentFive = { Name = "john" ; age = 17 ; major = "philosophy" }
    // studentFive.age <- studentFive.age + 2
    let studentList = [studentOne; studentTwo; studentThree ;studentFour; studentFive]
    studentList |> List.iter (fun s-> printf "Name: %s, Age: %d, Major: %s\n" s.Name s.age s.major)
```

---

```
let rec findStudent s = 
    match s with
    | [] -> None
    | x :: xs ->  if studentList.Name then return true else findStudent xs
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use member access:

```
studentList
|> List.sortBy (fun s -> s.age)
|> List.iter (fun s -> printf "Name: %s, Age: %d, Major: %s\n" s.Name s.age s.major)
```

or pattern matching (preferred IMO):

```
studentList
|> List.sortBy (fun { age=a } -> a)
|> List.iter (fun { Name=n; age=a; major=m } -> printf "Name: %s, Age: %d, Major: %s\n" n a m)
```

Comment: Thanks this really shows the functional aspect to the F#, but from what i understand could i also use this type of format for a search method as well? just given some input for user?

Comment: @bobEe : Your question is a bit too vague for me to make sense of.

Comment: Sorry, what i mean to say is could i make a search function given a name that iterates thought the list of records and returns true or false. I was thinking something like what i have edited aboe

Comment: "*could i make a search function given a name that iterates thought the list of records and returns true or false*" Yes, of course. Is that really your question?

Answer (score 2):

You can pipe your list through `List.sortBy` before doing `List.iter`:

```
studentList
|> List.sortBy (fun s -> s.age)
|> List.iter (fun s -> printf "Name: %s, Age: %d, Major: %s\n" s.Name s.age s.major)
```

As you can see, it takes a function to be used to get a value used for sorting. Passing `(fun s -> s.age)` will make the list be sorted by Age.